# async_task from django-q doesn't raise errors

Tags: python, django, django-q

It seems `django-q` doesn't detect error for unknown raison.
And `task.success` always return true even failure. It sound like
whatever is happening no error is raised. Shouldn't I get the exception error in the console or in the webpage?

Expected: When an error to achieve a task, `task.success` should be `False`. So the `else block` of my `hook function` wile be executed.

**Hook function**:

```
def str_hook(task):
    """Hook for async task that return a string."""
    asynchrone_task = AsynchroneTask.objects.get(id=task.id)
    asynchrone_task.time_taken = timedelta(seconds=task.time_taken())
    asynchrone_task.result = str(task.result)

    if task.success:
        asynchrone_task.status = AsynchroneTask.FINISHED
    else:
        asynchrone_task.status = AsynchroneTask.FAILED
    asynchrone_task.save()
```

**offload task**:

```
def upload_io_real_spents(request):
    batch_name = get_object_or_404(BatchName,
        pk="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")
    file_path = settings.IMPORTS_PATH + 'dbm.csv'
    task_id = async_task(
        task_upload_io_real_spents,
        file_path,
        hook=q_services.str_hook,
    )
    try:
        asynchrone_task = AsynchroneTask(
            id=task_id,
            title= 'Importing Consolidated DSPs data',
            dsp=batch_name,
            user=request.user
        )
    except Exception as e:
        messages.error(request, e.__cause__)
        return redirect("imports")
    else:    
        asynchrone_task.save()

    asynchrone_task.save() 
    messages.success(request, "Task successfully started.")
    return redirect('imports')
```